# Is this possible to create liquibase variable from SQL query?

Tags: sql, database, liquibase

In liquibase there is a possibility to define `<property>`, but it's constant.
Is there any ability to define some variable for `<databaseChangeLog>`, which is the result from SQL query?

```
<databaseChangeLog>
    <!-- something like this -->
    <property name="variable" query="SELECT id FROM Table WHERE name='test'" type="SQL"/>

    <changeSet>
        <update tableName="Table">
            <column name="columnName" value='text'/>
            <!-- and below use ${variable} -->
            <where>id="${variable}</where>
        </update>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: Can't you just put the SQL directly into the where section?

Comment: I can and I did in a such way, but I have a lot of places with duplicates, so try to find better solution.